# How can I make html input type date automatically update the range

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make this code automatically update the range. the minimum should always not less than 18 years and max not more than 70yrs on the day a client fill up this form is their html trick for this?

```html
<input type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" min="" max="">
```

Answer (score 2):

if you would like be automatically for a long terms you should use js

```
 (()=>{
     const birthdate = document.getElementById("birthdate");
    const min = new Date();
    const max = new Date();
    min.setFullYear( min.getFullYear() - 18)
    max.setFullYear( max.getFullYear() + 70)
    console.log(min, max)
    birthdate.setAttribute("min", ''+min.getFullYear());
    birthdate.setAttribute("max", ''+max.getFullYear());
 })()
```

Comment: https://gijgo.com/datepicker/configuration/minDate get also this in consideration